# Accessing constructor properties in class

Tags: javascript, class, scope, ecmascript-6, this

I don't understand JavaScript scope when it comes to object variables. I have the following class defined:

```
class DataHandler {
  constructor(boardIDA, boardIDB, accessToken, eventA, eventB) {
    this.times = [];
    this.eventA = eventA;
    this.eventB = eventB;
    this.apiURLA = "https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/" + boardIDA + "/events/" + eventA + "/?access_token=" +
      accessToken;
    this.apiURLB = "https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/" + boardIDB + "/events/" + eventB + "/?access_token=" + accessToken;
    this.eventListenerA = new EventSource(this.apiURLA);
    this.eventListenerB = new EventSource(this.apiURLB);
    this.addListener(this.eventListenerA,
      eventA);
    this.addListener(this.eventListenerB, eventB);
  }
  addListener(eventSrc, eventName) {
    eventSrc.addEventListener(eventName, function(info) {
      alert(eventName);
      var parsedData = JSON.parse(info.data);
      this.times.push(parsedData);
    });
  }
}
```

The issue is with `this.times`. I have declared it in the constructor. However, I can't seem to access it in `addListener` — I get an error saying that I'm trying to call `push` on `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in an event listener, `this` is usually the object that triggered the event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accessing it in `addListener`, you are trying to access it in the anonymous event handler, which is called with a different `this`.

```
addListener(eventSrc, eventName) {
  var handler = function(info) {
    alert(eventName);
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(info.data);
    this.times.push(parsedData);
  };
  eventSrc.addEventListener(eventName, handler.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: would changing the anonymous function (which you've now changed to handler, but thinking of original code) to an arrow function also work? therefore negating the need for bind - considering the code already uses ES2015 `class`, then why not use `=>` as well (if it's an alternative)

Comment: @JaromandaX - yes - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this

Comment: "*…called in a different scope*" might be better as "called with a different *this*" since the scope from which a function is called does not affect how its *this* is set. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - you are right, thank you